# oracle does not display output - anonymous block completed

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to display a message in oracle sql develper on oracle 11g.
Straight from the doc:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-mar/o21plsql-242570.html

```
DECLARE
  l_message  
  VARCHAR2 (100) := 'Hello World!';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_message);
END;
```

gives me a message:

> anonymous block completed

why?

Comment: try adding "SET SERVEROUTPUT ON"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to display a message in oracle sql develper on oracle 11g.

In **SQL Developer** tool, you need to view the `DBMS_OUTPUT` window.

[image]

Alternatively, you could use `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` and **execute the anonymous block as a script** or **press F5**.